# Operator overloading with dynamic allocated matrix

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm writting some code for teaching myself C++.

Does the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    int m, n;
    public: 
    float** value;

    Matrix(int m, int n)
    {
        value = new float*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            value[i] = new float[n];
        this->m = m; this->n = n;
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            delete[] value[i];      
        delete[] value;
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& A)
    {
        m = A.getLength();
        n = A.getWidth();

        value = new float*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            value[i] = new float[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                value[i][j] = A.value[i][j];    
    }

    int getLength(void) const
    {
        return m;
    }

    int getWidth(void) const
    {
        return n;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                cout << value[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B)
    {
        if (m != B.getLength() || n != B.getWidth())
            return Matrix(0, 0);

        Matrix C = Matrix(m, n);

        cout << value << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                C.value[i][j] = value[i][j] + B.value[i][j];

        return C;
    }


    void operator = (const Matrix& A)
    {
        m = A.getLength();
        n = A.getWidth();

        value = new float*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            value[i] = new float[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                value[i][j] = A.value[i][j];
    }

};


int main()
{
    Matrix A = Matrix(3, 3);


    A.value[0][0] = 1; A.value[0][1] = 2; A.value[0][2] = 3;
    A.value[1][0] = 4; A.value[1][1] = 5; A.value[1][2] = 6;
    A.value[2][0] = 7; A.value[2][1] = 8; A.value[2][2] = 9;

    Matrix B = Matrix (3, 3);
    B.value[0][0] = 1; B.value[0][1] = 2; B.value[0][2] = 3;
    B.value[1][0] = 4; B.value[1][1] = 5; B.value[1][2] = 6;
    B.value[2][0] = 7; B.value[2][1] = 8; B.value[2][2] = 9;


    Matrix C = A + B;
    cout << C.value << endl;
    C.print();

    return 0;    
}
```

Generate a memory leak at the part "Matrix C = A + B"? I don't know if the returned matrix is destroyed after the association is done. If yes, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You don't have a leak in `Matrix C = A + B;`, but your assignment operator is broken, so this would leak: `Matrix C(1,2); C = A+B;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statement

```
Matrix C = A + B;
```

there is no leak.

Though in your code the copy assignment operator is not used nevertheless your copy assignment operator does not free the memory previously allocated to the matrix of an object.
The copy assignment operator differs from the copy constructor in that that the object is already created and has an allocated matrix. Also you have to check whether there is the self assignment.

Also it should be declared as

```
Matrix & operator = (const Matrix& A)
```

As for `operator +` then it should be declared as

```
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B) const;
```

or as

```
const Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B) const;
```

Comment: About the assignment operator, why does D = C = A+B does not simply copy the value pointer, since then i will be returning a reference to *this object?

Comment: @user3422072 A+ B creates a temporary object that will be deleted. So you may not simply copy the value of the pointer. The memory pointed to by the ponter will be deleted when the temporary object will be in turn deleted.